# Scala type eraser

Tags: scala, generics, type-erasure, erasure

```
case class Thing[T](value: T)
def processThing(thing: Thing[_]) = {
  thing match {
    case Thing(value: Int) => "Thing of int"
    case Thing(value: String) => "Thing of string"
    case _ => "Thing of something else"
  }
}

println(processThing(Thing(1)))
println(processThing(Thing("hello")))
```

Above outputs `Thing of int` and `Thing of string`. My question is why the type info
is still available in runtime if type eraser kicks in?

Comment: Because you kind of persisted the type to runtime with pattern matching. `TypeTag`s work similarly.

Comment: There is no type info in runtime, but there is class info. When you do a pattern match of the form `foo: X` you are not checking for types _(even if the spec called it like that)_ but rather checking for class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not when type erasure kicks in, if you try this:

```scala
def processThing(thing: Thing[_]) = {
  thing match {
    case _: Thing[Int] => "Thing of int"
    case _: Thing[String] => "Thing of string"
    case _ => "Thing of something else"
  }
}

println(processThing(Thing("hello")))
```

You will get `Thing of int`. With `case Thing(value: Int)` you're basically doing a pattern matching with type assertion, I think it would be something like this:

```scala
def processThing(thing: Thing[_]) = {
  thing match {
    case Thing(value) if value.isInstanceOf[Int] => "Thing of int"
    case Thing(value) if value.isInstanceOf[String] => "Thing of string"
    case _ => "Thing of something else"
  }
}
```

Comment: You could not differentiate a `Thing[List[Int]]` from a `Thing[List[String]]`, that's where type erasure would kick in. But you could still extract first element of the list and pattern match on it and it would work.

Comment: @GaëlJ sure, but that's not the only place type erasure kicks in, whenever we do type matching on a generic type, type erasure happens, wether it's `Thing[Try[Option[List[Int]]]]`, or `Thing[Int] (in my fist code block)`, because in runtime, they're all "Thing"s, unless we somehow take control of the generic type parameter.